# javascript get key name from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

from

```
"data":[{"ja":"大阪市"},{"en":"Osaka"}]
```

I want to get `"ja"` and `"en"`.

I tried several ways...

```
data.map(function(_, i) { return i; });
```

it returns 
array of numbers.

```
console.log(Object.keys(Object.values(data)));
```

all trials return

```
(2) [0, 1]
0: 0
1: 1
```

what can I do ??
please answer me. thank you.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @MaheerAli I already said that. I want to ge  ["ja", "en"]

Comment: `data.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0])` Bad JSON design though. Would make far more sense if both keys and values just belonged to the same object.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen could you recommend? better than [0] ?

Comment: @horoyoio You can use `flatMap` I updated the answer

Comment: The reason for the `[0]` is that, as I stated, your JSON is badly designed.

Answer (score 14):

Use `map()` and return the first key the object. You can get keys using `Object.keys()`

```js
let data = [{"ja":"大阪市"},{"en":"Osaka"}]
let res = data.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);
console.log(res)
```

If you don't want to use `[0]` use `flatMap()`

```js
let data = [{"ja":"大阪市"},{"en":"Osaka"}]
let res = data.flatMap(x => Object.keys(x));
console.log(res)
```

**Note**: The second method will also get the other properties other than first. For example

```
[{"ja":"大阪市","other":"value"},{"en":"Osaka"}] //["ja","other","en"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let data = [{"ja":"大阪市"},{"en":"Osaka"}]
    
let res = data.reduce((arr, o) => {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((a, k) => {
     if (a.indexOf(k) == -1) a.push(k);
        return a;
     }, arr)
  }, []);
    
console.log(res);
```